# Add certificates and key in java for socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

Hi I am building myhsm connectivity from java application using a secure socket connection in java , MYHSM team have provided IPaddress and port along with 3 files for connectivity

1. CA_MYHSM_chain.crt
2. client_MYHSM.crt
3. client_MYHSM.key

how to add these certificates in java code while establishing a connection to their server IP address and port

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add public certificate to jvm local trust store by using following command:

```
JRE_HOME/bin/keytool  -import  -trustcacerts -alias certAlias  -file certFile -keystore trustStoreFile
```

More detail can be found here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19906-01/820-4916/geygn/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the response , but How to add a key to it along with chain certificate?

Comment: @AdarshBP you don't need to provide private key when adding certificate